# Unknown flowering tree, what is it?

Tags: identification, trees, magnolia

[image: flower]

[image: tree]

What kind of tree is this?  Blooming now in central Missouri, USA.

Some trees look like this (more bush-like), while others look more tree-like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is *Magnolia stellata*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia_stellata

Comment: Yes I agree with that one, beautiful and in flower in the uk at the moment.  This one is small, others are very large. Beautiful blooms, hopefully that's a keeper?

Comment: This isn't actually my tree, but one in the neighborhood that I am definitely considering planting when I get space.

Comment: It's worth it for sure.  Other small varieties also have more pink flowers.

Comment: I would have planted it, if it had had wildlife value.

Comment: @VividD  All plants have wildlife value.  We need to get rid of bark and non decomposed mulches people use to 'combat' weeds!  Plant only plants listed for your zone?